# Passing functions to directives angularjs 1.5

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', function ( $scope ) {
        $scope.doSum = function(x, y){
            console.log(x+y);
        };
    }
]);


<cmp data-fn="doSum(x, y)"></cmp>


app.directive('cmp', function(){ 
    return{

        templateUrl: 'ui/cmp.html'
        ,
        replace: true
        ,
        scope: { 
            dataFn: '&' 
        }
        ,
        controller: ['$scope' function($scope){

                var v = $scope.dataFn({x: 1, y: 2});

                console.log(v);

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Im trying to pass a function from a controller to a directive in angularjs 1.5. According to all tutorials this is how its done. But i cant get it to work. Can you please help me? The function is not passed at all and v results in undefined.

Comment: your `doSum` function should return the result `x+y` instead of doing a console log

Comment: Why would calling `doSum` with an object work? You'll note that you're calling `$scope.dataFn({x: 1, y: 2})` instead of `$scope.dataFn(1, 2)`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan that's the correct way to pass local values to an expression binding (makes x and y available in the html)

Comment: @floribon Huh, you learn something new every day. Thanks.

Comment: on the controller scope in the inspector: doSum:(x, y)
on the directive scope: dataFn:(b)
So the function isnt passed it seems. Also with return it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `data-*` prefix in your attribute. It is used to embed non standars HTML attributes.

Try to remove the data-* prefix from `data-fn` attribute. I'm sure will work.

I've made a [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/txfz9vxd/3/) for you...

[W3Schools data-* attr](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Comment: You are awesome :) thanks so much. It was the problem.